# Error in updating a database table using a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, database

There is problem with Query :

```
$outputs = rosy, rosmary; //array1

$filenames =2.2, 3.2; // array 2
```

Query:

```
$insert_col  = "UPDATE `lil` SET `D`='" .$output. "' WHERE `A`= '" .$filename. "'";// does not work
```

Instead of the arrays when i give single value, it works very fine, like :

```
$insert_col  = "UPDATE `lil` SET `D`='rosy' WHERE `A`= '2.2'"; // it works
```

for taking two arrays into the query i have written foreach loop, as follows

```
foreach (array_combine($outputs, $filenames) as $output => $filename) {
    $insert_col = "UPDATE `4` SET `D`='" . $output . "' WHERE `A`= '" . $filename . "'";
    echo $insert_col;
}
```

Please Help !!

Comment: you might run into trouble if you use the same names of your arrays as the `foreach` variables

Comment: It's seem strange that filenames are numeric? Do you mean that rosy "belongs" to 2.2 and rosmary "belongs" to 3.2 ?

Comment: for all we know those are just dummy values he quickly replaced for the sake of posting it on SO

Answer (score 0):

try using for loop. get the size of array and run for loop for that no of times

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$query = 'UPDATE lil SET D = CASE A';

foreach($arr as $k => $v)
    $query .= 'WHEN ' . $k . ' THEN ' . $v;

$query .= ' END';
```

Comment: The OP edited his question, yes,you right, i deleted my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$insert_col = 'UPDATE 4 SET D = CASE A';
foreach($arr as $output => $filename)
{
$insert_col .= 'WHEN ' . $output . ' THEN ' . $filename;
$insert_col .= ' END';
$insert_result= mysql_query($insert_col)or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
```

dint work @eli